# IE 10 , Windows 8 error : the value of the property webform_initcallback is null or undefined, not a function object

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, windows-8, internet-explorer-10

I am getting the below error while accessing my website using Ie 10(OS: windows 8).

"The value of the property webform_initcallback is null or undefined, not a function object."

I have .net framework 4.5 in my machine. It seems this should have been fixed in .net framework 4.5. But I am still getting this error.

Can anyone tell me why am I getting this error?Is there any hotfix available for this?

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET AJAX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed kb2600100 on server and i didn't get any error.